# From an array of objects, collect and remove duplicates for all attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given a set of data like:

```
[
  { name: 'apple',      color: 'red',    hasPeel: false },
  { name: 'banana',     color: 'yellow', hasPeel: true },
  { name: 'orange',     color: 'orange', hasPeel: true },
  { name: 'strawberry', color: 'red',    hasPeel: false }
]
```

I would like to get an object like:

```
{
  name: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry'],
  color: ['red', 'yellow', 'orange'],
  hasPeel: [true, false]
}
```

*(Grouped by properties, with duplicates removed)*

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

I've been playing around with different ES6 tricks and lodash helpers, but haven't found an efficient way to only iterate over the array once.

Comment: What was inefficient about your solution, can you show us some of your attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input = [{
    name: 'apple',
    color: 'red',
    hasPeel: false
  },
  {
    name: 'banana',
    color: 'yellow',
    hasPeel: true
  },
  {
    name: 'orange',
    color: 'orange',
    hasPeel: true
  },
  {
    name: 'strawberry',
    color: 'red',
    hasPeel: false
  }
];
const result = {};

for (const el of input) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(el)) {
    if (!result[key]) {
      result[key] = [value];
    } else if (!result[key].includes(value)) {
      result[key].push(value);
    }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with `reduce()` and `forEach()` methods to build object and ES6 `Set` to remove duplicate values from arrays.

```js
const data = [{"name":"apple","color":"red","hasPeel":false},{"name":"banana","color":"yellow","hasPeel":true},{"name":"orange","color":"orange","hasPeel":true},{"name":"strawberry","color":"red","hasPeel":false}]

const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  Object.keys(e).forEach(k => {
    if (!r[k]) r[k] = [e[k]]
    else r[k] = [...new Set(r[k]).add(e[k])]
  });
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

You could write this in shorter form like this.

```js
const data = [{ name: 'apple',      color: 'red',    hasPeel: false },{ name: 'banana',     color: 'yellow', hasPeel: true },{ name: 'orange',     color: 'orange', hasPeel: true },{ name: 'strawberry', color: 'red',    hasPeel: false }]

const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  Object.keys(e).forEach(k => r[k] = [...new Set(r[k]).add(e[k])]);
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Did you know that spreading everytime within a loop is a bad practice?

Comment: @Ele bad practice or not, recreating an array and a Set at every iteration is definetly not fast.

Comment: @JonasW. Yes, that's what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the functions `reduce`, `forEach` to group and function `includes` to check for duplicated.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'apple',      color: 'red',    hasPeel: false },{ name: 'banana',     color: 'yellow', hasPeel: true },{ name: 'orange',     color: 'orange', hasPeel: true },{ name: 'strawberry', color: 'red', hasPeel: false }];

var result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  Object.keys(c).forEach(k => {
    if (!(a[k] || (a[k] = [])).includes(c[k])) a[k].push(c[k]);
  });
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I upvoted because i dont understand the downvoter, and its at least not as bad as the currently most upvoted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see what you have tried along with the problem/s you were having, and why you found your solution/s inefficient. Anyway, here is yet another solution, it requires at least ES2018 or you can use babel to transpile it.

```js
const data = [{
    name: "apple",
    color: "red",
    hasPeel: false
  },
  {
    name: "banana",
    color: "yellow",
    hasPeel: true
  },
  {
    name: "orange",
    color: "orange",
    hasPeel: true
  },
  {
    name: "strawberry",
    color: "red",
    hasPeel: false
  }
];

const x = [...data.reduce((map, object) => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    if (map.has(key)) {
      map.get(key).add(value);
    } else {
      map.set(key, new Set([value]));
    }
  }

  return map;
}, new Map())].reduce((object, [key, set]) => ({
  ...object,
  [key]: [...set]
}), {});

console.log(x);
```